# PhantomJS fonts kerning issue

Tags: fonts, centos, phantomjs, kerning

Certain fonts letter spacing are mostly not symmetric - even have no gaps at all in some cases. 
The Server is "CentOS Linux release 7.0" (Had an older server version and this version gives better results but still not a good one)
phantomjs version is 1.9.8
The html that I use is

```
<p><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">10px</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></span></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">12px</span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;">ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">14px</span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:14px;">ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:14px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">16px</span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:16px;">ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:16px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">18px</span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:18px;">ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span></span></p>

<p style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:18px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></span></p>
```

I tried to install different fonts on the server manually in many formats - non helped. svg format is not acceptable since it can be copy paste and the file size is too big.

**Ariel with highlights**

[image: Ariel - highlighted]

**Ariel without highlights**

[image: Ariel]

**Times without highlights**

[image: Times]

What are my alternatives ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by the following

1. Compiled phantomjs 2.0.0 (stable release) from source on the machine
2. Copied the fonts from **ubuntu** -> /etc/fonts to /etc/fonts

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use an SVG font for the PDF rendering. This eliminated all of my letter-spacing (aka kerning) issues.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: svg will be rendered the same on all systems, but we had two issues with that If I remember correctly, cannot copy the text (using the mouse) and it took much more time to render the pdf's

Comment: this is correct; the SVG font cannot be selected for copy/paste and it will increase render time. however this was the only solution that eliminated the extra letter spacing issues.